# Claim based, token based and form authentication together in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

We are building a Single Page Application using Backbone + MVC 4. On server side (MVC 4), we have used MVCController (very Few) and webapi Controllers. In this application we have used form based authentication as of now. Also, we are storing user information in Sessions as well. Now, there is a requirement that client wants to use these webapi through his other windows/mobile applicaitons as well. We believe that we can expose all webapi controllers. But here are few concerns:

1) Currently, all the webapi are secured with Form authentication. But when these webapi will be used with windows/native mobile apps, form based authentication will not work (as it uses cookies internally). We will have to provide token based authentication for it. Is token based authentication is same as Claim based authentication?

2) Our authorization framework is little complex and we have to fetch all the permissions from database when user logs in and store them in session. For further requests, we fetch user permissions from session. Internally sessionId is passed in cookies. This will not work when WebApi will be hit from other applications (native and mobile). We can think of removing session usage from application if we can figure out any other approach to store this information on server.

If nothing works, we can think of creating one more project where we will replicate all the webapi and use token based/claim based authentication there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) Token based authentication provides the means for performing Claims based authentication. It allows you to transmit claims on HTTP requests, and verify that the claims came from a trusted source by performing signature validation.

You should secure your API with a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/). In your API, you check for the existence of the JWT token in the incoming request headers and if one exists, you use a token handler package to decode the token into a ClaimsPrincipal.

Once you have a principal, you can apply any authorization rules you like to your API endpoints using the standard filter attributes

2) Web API's should be stateless, you should remove Session usage from your API layer.

What you need to consider are...

i) How does a user uniquely identify themselves within your system? Do you have a 'customer id' \ 'user id' or some other identifier?  (AuthN)

ii) Once you can uniquely identify someone, how do you decide what resources that identity is allowed to access (AuthZ)

Do you absolutely need to load all of the permissions from the database when the user logs in, or just those permissions that allow you to uniquely identify the login?

You can design a JWT token that has a set of claims that allow you to pass the token on API requests, doing so means you no longer need to store the data on the server as the authn\authz information is now part of the HTTP request.

Good design is required here. Too much information in the JWT token, every request to your API will have large payload. Not enough information, your API will need to go and get any additional data it needs to make authorization decisions. You will need to decide what the correct balance is.

Have a look at [Identity Server on Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3). It has some useful demo projects, and good links to general authentication topics.